# Ubuntu 14.04 - Gnome - No Login - Black screen and forcibly switched out from console terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, drivers, login

I'll try to explain in detail cause this problem arose after trying to solve another problem:

My laptop has Ubuntu 14.04 (GRUB dual boot with windows 10, single SSD with 3 partitions) and I got no login screen after switching from generic graphic driver to NVidia drivers (WHQL 384 I think, don't remember exact version number).

I somehow managed to get the login screen back by booting in debug mode and resetting to the default graphic settings but the login screen was stuck in the (in)famous login loop (always back to the login screen after inserting username and password).

Thanks to Mr.Google I found 3 ways to solve it:

- check ownership of xuathority is the actual user (it was ok)
- check permissions of /tmp (it was ok)
- unity somehow got stuck, try to install gnome

I installed Gnome, at the GDM vs lightgdm selection I choose GDM (maybe this was my error, did it without really checking the difference).

Now when I boot up the pc, after the Gnome splash screen I get to a black screen with an underscore in the top left (NOT blinking).
If I try to switch to the console terminal (ctrl-alt-f3) I get to the terminal but automatically switch back to the dark screen after a couple of seconds, I can barely login that way, it requires 2-3 attempts to insert username plus 2-3 attempts to insert the password.

Any help to solve this and get back my desktop?
After a couple of days I'm at my wits end but I'd really like to avoid reinstalling the entire Ubuntu partition with the extra applications.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help.

p.s. note that I'm not an expert Linux user, just need to program a few of things on Eclipse there for school projects

p.p.s. I checked a number of other questions before asking. Not saying that there isn't the answer out there, just I didn't find it and didn't find anybody else talking about the console terminal switching forcefully to the black screen.

Comment: Install a recent Ubuntu version that is supported would be by far the easiest option for you. 14.04 is now 7 years old

Comment: I know but I'd like to avoid to reinstall that plus all the other applications I need and reconfigure those if it's solvable in a faster way.

Comment: If you have good backups, a reinstall is very quick. You need at minimum your /home, perhaps /etc, list of installed apps and if using Eclipse where ever you have saved that. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997